# Как узнать размеры выполняющего окна браузера?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Я новичёк в Javascript и мне необходимо узнать размеры выполняющего окна браузера, и задать эти размеры в `<div>`. Как мне это сделать ?

Скрипт я вроде уже нашел:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //IE5+, Mozilla 1.0+, Opera 7+
    function getClientWidth() {
        return document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat' && !window.opera ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.clientWidth;
    }

    function getClientHeight() {
        return document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat' && !window.opera ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight;
    }
</script>
```

Как задать эти значения `<div>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var w=window.innerWidth,
     h=window.innerHeight; // получаем ширину и высотц экрана
document.getElementById("your_div_id").style.width=w+"px";
document.getElementById("your_div_id").style.height=h+"px";
// естествтенно, для целевого ДИВа нужно задать конкретный ИД и поставить его вместо your_div_id
```

здесь не учтена кроссбраузерность и наличие/отсутствие полосы прокрутки, но для первичного понимания этот пример годится

Answer (score 2):

Смотреть в сторону `media-queries`, если Вам нужно адаптивная верстка.
Есть отличный эмулятор для IE6-8 - [Respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

Что каcается javascript - есть свойство [`window.screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen).

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про окно браузера, то screen.width, screen.height - возвращает общую ширину (высоту) пользовательского экрана, в px.